# How to move a MySQL database to an external hard disk?

Tags: mysql, macos

I am running OS X 10.5 and I do not know much about MySQL configuration.  I am using a local MySQL database to deposit data from an application but it is getting close to my hard disk's capacity.  What do I need to do to get the database stored on my external hard disk?  Where can I get documentation to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use mysqldump to create a new database on your external disk.

The point your application at that instance of the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) if you want something a bit more graphical, connect to your local databases then hit export. Then you'll have a .sql backup of them, you can use this to restore it later on.